# error when I run Deploy-Eflow in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

(run in `PS C:\Windows\system32>` prompt):

```
$msiPath = $([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/AzEFLOWMSI_1_4_LTS_X64" -OutFile $msiPath
$msiPath = $([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/AzEFLOWMSI_1_4_LTS_ARM64" -OutFile $msiPath
Start-Process -Wait msiexec -ArgumentList "/i","$([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))","/qn"
Deploy-Eflow
```

> ```
> Deploy-Eflow : The term 'Deploy-Eflow' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
> executable program. Check if you spelled the name correctly, or if you included a path, check that
> that path is correct and try again.
> En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
> + Deploy-Eflow
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Deploy-Eflow:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

- Download Hyper V
- Try downloading the latest version of powershell.
- Find out if you had any IoT Edge apps installed
- I tried looking in the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'd guess: install suitable *AzEFLOW* package - **either** `X64` **or** `ARM64` (not both).

Comment: Both have to be installed because the official documentation asks for both. Here is the link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-on-windows-symmetric?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=visual-studio-code                                                                                            I think the error is in the io.path:: combine, but i am no sure

Comment: You misunderstand the linked document. Learn more about _processor architecture_: [difference between X64 and ARM64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/10614/what-is-the-difference-between-x64-and-arm64), [App package architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/msix/package/device-architecture). [difference between ARM64 and AMD64](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-ARM64-and-AMD64-And-which-one-is-faster), and more (google for *"arm64" vs. "amd64"*).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. Josef's feedback is correct. You wouldn't need to execute both set of the commands. The documentation statement where it states "run each of the following commands to download IoT Edge for Linux on Windows" is misleading. Utilize the feedback section at the bottom of the page and report this feedback to the team to correct this.
[image]

Since you are working on Windows machine, you would need to set the `$msipath` for the processor `X64/AMD64`. This section refers to the Azure Eflow end point `https://aka.ms/AzEFLOWMSI_1_4_LTS_X64` which is compatible with Windows machine.
Notice that after you set this parameters and execute the command `Start-Process -Wait msiexec -ArgumentList "/i","$([io.Path]::Combine($env:TEMP, 'AzureIoTEdge.msi'))","/qn","INSTALLDIR=D:\EFLOW", "VHDXDIR=D:\EFLOW-VHDX"` you can find that `Azure IoT Edge LTS` gets installed on your Windows machine.

Review the installed programs on your Windows machine to validate this.
[image]

Once you have this installed, you can run the `Deply-Eflow` command without any issues. Refer the below image.

[image]