# EFLOW and IP Address Failure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I have been working this a couple of days, but after I can't figure out why the IP address is not being assigned to the EFLOW VM.  I have tried this both the default switch, as well as an External Switch that I created, using a static IP address.  Either way, the script to install eflow ends at the same place, as there is NO IPaddress assigned to the VM.
[image: Deloyment of Eflow]
[image]

The command use to start this process (after downloading and installing the image, starting the process - as per this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-on-windows-symmetric?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal#install-iot-edge)

The command I used to start the EFLow deploy was this:

> Deploy-Eflow -vSwitchName "EFLOWSwitch" -vswitchType "External"
> -ip4Address 192.168.1.220 -ip4GatewayAddress 192.168.1.254 -ip4PrefixLength 24

and the IPConfig output of the External Switch:
[image]

Comment: reference [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76240660/error-when-i-run-deploy-eflow-in-powershell)

Comment: Hi @codeputer Can you try enclosing the values for ip4Address and ip4GatewayAddress in quotes and see if that makes any difference.  Refer the following syntax `Deploy-Eflow -acceptEula 'yes' -acceptOptionalTelemetry 'yes' -vswitchName "EFLOW Switch" -ip4Address "169.254.61.100" -ip4GatewayAddress "169.254.61.1" -vswitchType 'Internal' -cpuCount 2 -memoryInMB 3072 -ip4PrefixLength 24`

Comment: I found out the problem, I had connected via SSH to too many devices, and their is a limit in the script when attempting to connec to the VM.  I used "ssh-add -d" to remove all cache ids (?).  After that it worked like a charm.  Added and "edge issue" to the Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, I had connected via SSH to too many devices, and there is a limit in the script when attempting to connect to the VM.  I used "ssh-add -d" to remove all cache ids (?).  After that, it worked like a charm.  Added an "edge issue" to GitHub.